# How can I further improve Oracle 12.1 performance on RDS m4.large instance?

Tags: performance, database, oracle, rds

I'm having performance issues with my current Oracle setup. Queries are taking half a second and I can't figure out how to speed it up further.

I've upgraded my RDS instance from a t2.medium to m4.large, created an index for the two columns I use in the where clause for all my queries, and limited my query to return a single row.

My tables (there are 5 in total - the schemas for which isn't my own design) have ~700 columns and as little as 7 rows and as many as 160,000 rows.

No matter which table I query (directly from SQL Developer or my application) it takes about half a second. If I run all my queries together it still takes about half a second.

All my queries are basically the same for each of the 5 tables.

```
SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(auto) */ * FROM (SELECT VALUE_I_WANT FROM TABLE_I_CARE_ABOUT WHERE (CLAUSE_ONE = 'X' AND CLAUSE_TWO = 'Y')) WHERE ROWNUM=1;
```

As I mentioned I have indexes on all these tables for columns CLAUSE_ONE and CLAUSE_2.

What else can I do to try and bring this query down to a much smaller fraction of a second?

Comment: You are more likely to get a good answer to this question by posting (probably a more specific question) on our sister site [dba.se].

Comment: Thank you Michael. Any tips on how I may make this more specific? I'm not a DBA so all I could think to do was give a full recount of where I'm at and what I've so far done.

Comment: I suggest [going through this](https://community.oracle.com/thread/503834) and adding all the relevant information into your new question.